# Join and sum on subset of rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which stores date ranges and some associated colums:

```
        date_start    date_end ... lots of other columns ...
1       2016-07-01  2016-07-02
2       2016-07-01  2016-07-03
3       2016-07-01  2016-07-04
4       2016-07-02  2016-07-07
5       2016-07-05  2016-07-06
```

and another dataframe of Pikachu sightings indexed by date:

```
              pikachu_sightings
      date
2016-07-01                    2
2016-07-02                    4
2016-07-03                    6
2016-07-04                    8
2016-07-05                   10
2016-07-06                   12
2016-07-07                   14
```

For each row in the first df I'd like to calculate the sum of pikachu_sightings within that date range (i.e., `date_start` to `date_end`) and store that in a new column. So would end up with a df like this (numbers left in for clarity):

```
        date_start    date_end    total_pikachu_sightings
1       2016-07-01  2016-07-02                      2 + 4
2       2016-07-01  2016-07-03                  2 + 4 + 6
3       2016-07-01  2016-07-04              2 + 4 + 6 + 8
4       2016-07-02  2016-07-07   4 + 6 + 8 + 10 + 12 + 14
5       2016-07-05  2016-07-06                    10 + 12
```

If I was doing this iteratively I'd iterate over each row in the table of date ranges, select the subset of rows in the table of sightings that match the date range and perform a sum on it - but this is way too slow for my dataset:

```
for range in ranges.itertuples():
    sightings_in_range = sightings[(sightings.index >= range.date_start) & (sightings.index <= range.date_end)]
    sum_sightings_in_range = sightings_in_range["pikachu_sightings"].sum()
    ranges.set_value(range.Index, 'total_pikachu_sightings', sum_sightings_in_range)
```

This is my attempt at using pandas, but fails because the length of the two dataframes does not match (and even if they did, there's probably some other flaw in my approach):

```
range["total_pikachu_sightings"] =
    sightings[(sightings.index >= range.date_start) & (sightings.index <= range.date_end)
             ["pikachu_sightings"].sum()
```

I'm trying to understand what the general approach/design should look like as I'd like to aggregate with other functions too, `sum` just seems like the easiest for an example. Sorry if this is an obvious question - I'm new to pandas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that `pikachu_sightings` has a datetime index and is sorted.

```
p = pikachu_sightings.squeeze() # force into a series
p.index = pd.to_datetime(p.index)
p = p.sort_index()
```

Then make sure your `date_start` and `date_end` are datetime.

```
df.date_start = pd.to_datetime(df.date_start)
df.date_end   = pd.to_datetime(df.date_end)
```

Then its simply

```
df.apply(lambda x: p[x.date_start:x.date_end].sum(), axis=1)

0     6
1    12
2    20
3    54
4    22
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks that's an elegant solution, and works! Is the code in that last line still using pandas? I ask because it's really slow for a large dataset (30 seconds for 50,000 date ranges and 6000 rows in pikachu_sightings - and wanted to process a much larger dataset!)

Comment: @Matt it is pandas.  Not vectorized.

Answer (score 3):

A sketch of a vectorized solution:

Start with a `p` as in piRSquared's answer.

Make sure `date_` cols have `datetime64` dtypes, i.e.:

```
df['date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
```

Then calculate cumulative sums:

```
psums = p.cumsum()
```

and

```
result = psums.asof(df.date_end) - psums.asof(df.date_start)
```

It's not yet the end, though. `asof` returns the last good value, so it sometimes will take the exact start date and sometimes not (depending on your data). So, you have to adjust for that. (If the date frequency is `day`, then probably moving the index of `p` an hour backwards, e.g. `-pd.Timedelta(1, 'h')`, and then adding `p.asof(df.start_date)` might do the trick.)